# Google chrome is reading characters backwards

Tags: google-chrome, browser

Google Chrome is my favorite browser, and I can't imagine going on without it. Suddenly (without closing and re-opening) the browser; chrome has been reading characters upside down, very weird:

[image]

Chrome version:

[image]

I tried restarting my browser and my MAC (running OS X Yosemite 10.10), but the error keeps on coming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to `chrome://help` (type into the address bar and go) and then update to the latest version of chrome a fix was recently posted by the chromium team.

You can follow the latest on this issue here (pretty interesting reading):

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=479097

Answer (score 1):

A temporary fix has already been posted by @thisisgregory on stackoverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29764107/google-chrome-search-bar-text-upside-down

> Go into your Chrome Settings > Advanced Settings > un-check Use
>   hardware acceleration when available.
>
> Not sure why but it fixed my issue.

Comment: Answers that only contain links, even to other stack exchange sites, are frowned upon. It is better to extract the relevant part(s) and leave the link as a reference. For more information, see this [meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259). Just giving you an idea to why you were downvoted. +1 from me to off set :)