# Google Chrome Search Bar Text Upside Down

Tags: google-chrome

I don't know really how to ask this as a question because I'm not sure what is going on: in my Google Chrome browser the search bar's text is upside down when I try to type in it or click on it, everything else on the page is the proper way and when I click off the search bar the text goes back to normal. Is there something that I may have done to have this happen? It just started today and it is really really annoying. The only inference I have seen about this happening to someone else was on here: http://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/336245/ and although several people claimed to have a similar problem that started occuring this week no one has been able to solve it

Comment: Cross-posting is frowned upon, and this question has already been asked here: [Google chrome is reading characters backwards](http://superuser.com/questions/903173/google-chrome-is-reading-characters-backwards).

Comment: it was closed ( i asked it there) and was asked to send it here

Comment: Investigate before scrutinizing or carry on your way

Comment: Strange, they should have migrated it. Anyhow it's still a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for some people: Go into your Chrome Settings > Advanced Settings > un-check Use hardware acceleration when available.

But for other users it does not. I am one of those users it doesnt work for but I leave this answer here if it helps as credited from here (where I asked this question on stackoverflow): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29764107/google-chrome-search-bar-text-upside-down